# What's the best code for performance to check if a .net arraylist have two or more items with the same value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, for-loop, arraylist, items

I don't want check if an item with a value exists in the arraylist,

I want to know the best code for performance to get how many occurrences of the same item with the same value exists in an arraylist.

I can do something like

```
For Each s As string In myArrayList
[...]
Next
```

however is there a better code of that?

Comment: Arraylist should be avoided entirely in .Net 2.0 and later. There's no good reason to use it any more.

Comment: just a curiosity @joel, how do u would implement a string array for example with the same capabilities of an arraylist?

Comment: I would use a List(Of String)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to see how many times a particular element is repeated in a `ArrayList`.  If so try the following

```
Dim table As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each s As String in myArrayList
  Dim count As Integer = 0
  If table.TryGetValue(s, count) Then
    table(s) = count + 1
  Else 
    table(s) = 1
  End If
Next

For Each pair in table 
  If pair.Value >= 2 Then
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key)
  End If
Next
```

Note: This assumes that you are using Visual Studio 2005 or higher.  If not please let me know and I'll provide a 2003 compatible answer

Answer (score 2):

[`Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx) your `ArrayList` first and then use [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45w0c52f.aspx). This should give even better performance than the Dictionary approach, since you don't need to create another collection or loop the existing completely to lookup items.

Of course this is far from being elegant and readable code but it's **fast**(~2 sec. for 10 MM lookups).

```
Dim letters = New ArrayList() From {"A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "C", "E", "cC", "C", "E", "A", "c", "C", "F", "C"}
letters.Sort() ' just needed once and only if it's not already sorted 
Dim lookupItem = "C"
Dim itemCount = 0 ' correct result: 5 (case-sensitive) 
Dim index = letters.BinarySearch(lookupItem)
If index > -1 Then
    Dim nextIndex = index
    While letters(nextIndex).Equals(lookupItem)
        itemCount += 1
        nextIndex += 1
    End While
    If index > 0 Then
        ' look into the other direction since BinarySearch 
        ' does not necessarily return the first index 
        ' in this example index is 6 instead of 5
        Dim prevIndex = index - 1
        While letters(prevIndex).Equals(lookupItem)
            itemCount += 1
            prevIndex -= 1
        End While
    End If
End If
```

Note that the type of your `value` should implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) or you define a custom Comparer which you can pass to `BinarySearch`.

Btw, instead of an `ArrayList` you should use strong tyed generic Lists, for instance a [`List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

---

**Edit**: Because i've already mentioned generic `Lists`, i will show you another approach using a `Lists(Of T)` already wrapped in a convenient extension method:

```
Public Module ListExtensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ItemCount(Of T)(ByVal sortedList As List(Of T), item As T) As Int32
        Dim count = 0
        Dim index = sortedList.BinarySearch(item)
        Dim nextIndex = index
        If index > -1 Then
            While nextIndex < sortedList.Count AndAlso sortedList(nextIndex).Equals(item)
                count += 1
                nextIndex += 1
            End While
            If index > 0 Then
                Dim prevIndex = index - 1
                While prevIndex > 0 AndAlso sortedList(prevIndex).Equals(item)
                    count += 1
                    prevIndex -= 1
                End While
            End If
        End If
        Return count
    End Function
End Module
```

Now you can everywhere get the itemcount of any object in any kind of List, for instance a `List(Of String)` and a `List(Of Integer)` including several measurements:

```
Const chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim letters = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(Function(i) chars(rnd.Next(0, chars.Length)).ToString).ToList
Dim letterTime = New Stopwatch
letterTime.Start()
letters.Sort()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = letters.ItemCount("C")
Next
letterTime.Stop()

Dim numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(Function(i) rnd.Next(100000)).ToList()
Dim numberTime = New Stopwatch
numberTime.Start()
numbers.Sort()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = numbers.ItemCount(4711)
Next
numberTime.Stop()

' measure the LINQ Where-Extension

Dim letterTimeWhere = New Stopwatch
letterTimeWhere.Start()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = letters.Where(Function(str) str.Equals("C")).Count()
Next
letterTimeWhere.Stop()

Dim numberTimeWhere = New Stopwatch
numberTimeWhere.Start()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = numbers.Where(Function(int) int = 4711).Count()
Next
numberTimeWhere.Stop()
```

Result for searching 100000 Strings/Integers in Lists with 100000 items.

```
Dim time = String.Format("String(Binary): {0} Numbers(Binary): {1} String(LINQ): {2} Numbers(LINQ): {3}", letterTime.Elapsed.ToString, numberTime.Elapsed.ToString, letterTimeWhere.Elapsed.ToString, numberTimeWhere.Elapsed.ToString)
' String(Binary): 00:00:05.2602861 Numbers(Binary): 00:00:00.0350816 
' String(LINQ)  : 00:04:56.8772996 Numbers(LINQ)  : 00:01:43.2139190 
' => Binary 55 x faster                => Binary 2950 x faster
```

**Note**: The LINQ comparison is certainly unfair since `Where` needs to loop every item and `BinarySearch` can [optimize the search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Performance). Just for the sake of completeness.

---

By the way, @JaredPars `Dictionary` is much faster when the are many duplicates in the list(hence the Dictionary is small-sized like in the letter sample.

```
String(Dict)  : 00:00:00.0224329     Numbers(Dict): 00:00:00.0216544
```

**I admit defeat** ;)

Here's his Dictionary as extension:

```
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToCountLookup(Of T)(ByVal list As List(Of T)) As Dictionary(Of T, Int32)
    Dim table As New Dictionary(Of T, Integer)
    For Each s As T In list
        Dim count As Int32 = 0
        If table.TryGetValue(s, count) Then
            table(s) = count + 1
        Else
            table(s) = 1
        End If
    Next
    Return table
End Function
```

And you can use it in this way, you need `TryGetValue` since the `Dictionary` might not contain that key:

```
Dim letterLookuptable = letters.ToCountLookup()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = 0
    letterLookuptable.TryGetValue("C", count)
Next

Dim intLookuptable = numbers.ToCountLookup()
For i = 1 To 100000
    Dim count = 0
    intLookuptable.TryGetValue(4711, count)
Next
```